# Russian Sign Language

Tags: перевод

Is there a sign language that can I find for Russian ? I am interested in how it compare with American Sign Language.

Comment: In the USSR some time in 1980s all news broadcasts were accompanied with sign language doubling. You can search for these recordings in the internet.

Comment: @Anixx    That's interesting...how many are there deaf living in Russia ?

Comment: Not only in 1980. I definitely remember that in 1990s news on some channels were also with sign-language dubbing.
And about number of deaf people... I don't think that percentage is much different than in USA.

Answer (score 5):

Of course Russian has a sign language. You can look for "**Русский жестовый язык**" and "**Сурдоперевод**" in the internet.

Start, say, from [this Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA)

Answer (score 2):

Russian has its own sign language, and I can share a textbook of it, in Russian, [Гейльман И.Ф., «Знакомьтесь: ручная речь», Москва, «Загрей», 2001](http://www.mediafire.com/download/b2acb0d6uv6faq3/), 2 MB.

Comment: Thank you. While I don't understand in Russian yet but it is a start that I wanted to learn the ABC between the two language...

Comment: @PROBERT - The text in the book (but not under the images) is OCRed, so you can copy the text and use the https://translate.google.com/ to translate it, that site has greatly improved.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the translate on google site. It's good. How long does it take you to learn Russian ?

Comment: @PROBERT - That depends on how much time you devote to learning Russian every day and on your overall talent in learning languages. An hour every day will make you be able to talk about everyday issues after about 3 months of studying Russian.